# Prints output twice when reading a file

Tags: python

I have written the following code to write a file, convert it into integer values, save that file and then read and convert it back to the original string. However, it prints the output twice.

My code is

```
def write():
    sentence=input('What is your Statement?:')
    name=input('Name your file:')
    sentence=sentence.lower()
    words=sentence.split(' ')
    file_register=set()
    F_output=[]
    position=[]

for i in words:
    if i not in file_register:
        F_output.append(i)
        file_register.add(i)

for x in words:
    for y in range(len(F_output)):
        if x==F_output[y]:
            position.append(y)
name+='.txt'
with open(str(name),'w') as f:
    f.write(str(len(position)) + '\n')
    for c in range(len(position)):
        f.write(str(position[c]) + '\n')
    f.write(str(len(F_output)) + '\n')
    for d in range(len(F_output)):
        f.write(str(F_output[d] + '\n'))
    f.close
    global name
    global position

def read1():
    savefile=[]
    output=('')  
    with open(name,'r') as file_open:
        num=int(file_open.readline())
        while num!=0:
            a1=file_open.readline()
            a1_split=a1.split('\n')
            position.append(int(a1_split[0]))
            num-=1
        file_integer=int(file_open.readline())
        while file_integer!=0:
            word_s=file_open.readline()
            word_split=word_s.split()
            savefile.append(word_split)
            file_integer-=1

    for n in range(len(position)):
        a=position[n]
        output+=str(savefile[a])+('')
    global output

write()
read1()
print('Your file is: '+output)
```

I have tried searching, but I cannot find an answer for it. I am fairly new to Python and any help is appreciated.

Comment: please fix your code snippet indentation.

Comment: Using globals in this way is almost always a bad idea

Comment: @brianpck your can drop the "in this way" part - and as far is I'm concerned, you can also drop the "almost" ;)

Comment: I am not sure what you use as an editor... however you will learn/teach your self a lot if you use a debugger to step through your code line by line. This way you can see when each printing instance of your output occurs. 

You can also insert other print statements between different portions of your code to smoke out where your second, or rather first, output printing occurs.

More than likely this is a learning exercise... and your failing to accomplish the goal of the exercise by not trouble shooting your code on your own.

Answer (score 0):

In `write()`, you declare `position` as global. In `read1()`, you don't declare it as global, but since you never create a local `position` variable it's the global one that gets used. So you end up populating it twice: once in `write()` then once again in `read1()`.

To make a long story short: dont use globals. You don't need them.

Also, you'd find your code way easier to read, understand and debug by  1/ using better naming, 2/ writing simple, short functions that do one single thing, works on their inputs (arguments) and return values (the same arguments should produce the same output values), and 3/ properly using python's `for` loop.

Here's an example of what your code could looks like following those rules:

```
def parse(sentence):
    sentence=sentence.lower()
    words=sentence.split(' ')

    register=set()
    output = []
    positions = []

    for word in words:
        if word not in register:
            output.append(word)
            register.add(word)

    for word in words:
        for index in range(len(output)):
            if word == output[index]:
                positions.append(index)

    return output, positions

def write(path, output, positions):
    with open(path, 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(len(positions)) + '\n')
        for index in positions:
            f.write(str(index) + '\n')
        f.write(str(len(output)) + '\n')
        for word in output:
            f.write(word + '\n')


def read(path):
    words = []
    positions = []

    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        poscount = int(f.readline().strip())
        while poscount:
            line = f.readline().strip()
            pos = int(line)
            positions.append(pos)
            poscount -= 1

        wordcount = int(f.readline().strip())
        while wordcount:
            line = f.readline()
            word = line.strip()
            words.append(word)
            wordcount -= 1

    output = []
    for index in positions:
        word = words[index]
        output.append(word)

    return output, positions



def main():
    sentence = input('What is your Statement?:')
    path = input('Name your file:')
    if not path.endswith(".txt"):
        path +=".txt"

    source_out, source_positions = parse(sentence)
    write(path, source_out, source_positions)

    read_out, read_positions = read(path)
    print("your file is: {}".format(read_out))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This code is still overly complicated IMHO but at least it's mostly readable, doesn't use any global, and should be easier to test.

Comment: Thanks, I uses idle and are fairly new so thanks for the help.